# unbiased estimator for the parameter

Tags: statistics

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be i.i.d.  sample from Poisson distribution with parameter λ.
How to construct an unbiased estimator for the parameter function $ψ(λ) =λ^2e^{−λ}$ with the help of $X_1$ only?

I know that $T(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$ is a sufficient statistic for λ. Also, $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$ is unbiased for λ. I tried to use Rao-Blackwell Theorem for ψ(λ).  But, I get stuck to proceed. I was wondering if someone can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple:

$$T'=2\cdot I_{\{X_1=2\}}$$

would do what you want:

$$E[T']=2P(X_1=2)=\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda}$$

Then you can use Rao-Blackwell (in fact Lehmann–Scheffe theorem) to find the UMVUE